# Xcode Import Localization not shows in Localization file

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I am trying to import the translated file to Xcode Project but the translated strings are not visible in the Localization file. Even I am getting some warnings while importing and I suspect that it is reason for not showing those strings in the Localization file. I am adding screen shots and details below.

In the screen shot, I am highlighting one of the string which is not working as expected.

[image]

This is the string and file which I received when I did the export from the Xcode. It shows 3 different keys with same string "See All". I have converted these strings and after that it looks like below.

[image]

Conversion looks correct to me, so I have imported the file in my Xcode project.
Now, When I did the import it shows me the change. I am attaching the screen shot.

[image]

I have checked ids are same in both the above files. Even it shows in screen shot as well.

However I am getting warning while importing.
[image]

Even with these warning it allows me to import the file. Once I import the file it didn't shows the "See All" string. I am attaching the Localization where string is not visible.
[image]

I am not sure why it is not showing over there.
I have checked  path as well, it is correct. Export and Import both files have the keys and string both.

How can I add these translations? Do I need to fix these warnings? If yes then How can I do that. I have 3 different type of warnings.
Can any one help me here?